# keras import fails "no module named contrib.ctc"

Tags: keras

On OSX El CApitan 10.11.6 I've installed theano & tensorflow fine. But the keras install is not happy as seen from the trace below. I've seen this reported [on github issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4510) but with no solution there, only a suggestion to post here on SO.

```
>>>import theano
>>>
>>> import tensorflow
>>> 
>>> import keras
     File "/Users/petercotton/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 6, in <module>
        import tensorflow.contrib.ctc as ctc
    ImportError: No module named contrib.ctc`
```

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with Keras, not TensorFlow and a [known issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/3436#issuecomment-240230596).
A workaround is mentioned [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/3436#issuecomment-241169473) but that would mean that you have to modify Keras code (`keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py`).

Luckily, it seems that this issue is [fixed](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/3827) in the master branch of Keras.

Comment: it seems issue was not fxd in mstr branch!!

>>from keras.models import Sequential
Using TensorFlow backend.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/KERAS/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/keras/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import backend
  File "/home/user/KERAS/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.1.1-py2.7.egg/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
ImportError: No module named ctc

Comment: See [related issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538920/keras-import-error-tensorflow-backend/40541154?noredirect=1#comment68322342_40541154) for a solution.