# Keras Import Error Tensorflow backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/CJL/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in <module>()
      4 try:
----> 5     from tensorflow.python.ops import ctc_ops as ctc
      6 except ImportError:

ImportError: cannot import name 'ctc_ops'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-c74e2bd4ca71> in <module>()
----> 1 import keras

/Users/CJL/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
----> 2 from . import backend
      3 from . import datasets
      4 from . import engine
      5 from . import layers

/Users/CJL/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py in <module>()
     67 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     68     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 69     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     70 else:
     71     raise Exception('Unknown backend: ' + str(_BACKEND))

/Users/CJL/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in <module>()
      5     from tensorflow.python.ops import ctc_ops as ctc
      6 except ImportError:
----> 7     import tensorflow.contrib.ctc as ctc
      8 
      9 import numpy as np

ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.ctc'
```

Seems like is an problem with Keras and not Tensorflow according to this post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661433/keras-import-fails-no-module-named-contrib-ctc)
I was wondering if this has been fixed yet?

Comment: Oh actually, that's a problem with Keras. You're not supposed to do that. You're supposed to use `tf.nn.*`. Let me comment on the github PR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem between Keras and tensorflow. You should change this [fix](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/3827) to use something like

```
if hasattr(tf.contrib, 'ctc'):
  ctc = tf.contrib.ctc  # old version
else:
  ctc = tf.nn  # New official version.
```

The current "official" way to access the ctc operations are in `tf.nn`, for instance, `tf.nn.ctc_loss`.

Comment: What file is this in the tensorflow library? Thanks.

Comment: It's [keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L6). Don't try to import. If you are using a recent version of tensorflow, `ctc = tf.nn` should suffice.

Comment: I'm still getting this error after I changed the code "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib' has no attribute 'ctc'"

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it and let me import without issues.

Answer (score -3):

If keras is giving an import problem and you are facing "no module named keras" even if you have installed it.

1. Just upgrade your pip by:

> ```
> python -m pip install –upgrade pip
> ```

1. Re-install upgraded keras and tensorflow by:

> ```
> pip install keras
> pip install tensorflow
> ```

Hope it will solve the problem. If not, try upgrading your conda (Anaconda) and then do steps 1 to 3 above again.